# Add extra margin to div dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

Using jQuery I'd like to add additional top-margin to a div 'foo', but only if another div 'foo2' contains more than two images.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#foo2 > img').length > 2 ? $('#foo').css('margin-top', '10px') : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#foo2 img').length>2) $('#foo').css('margin-top', 243);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually like to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` (or the consolidated `toggleClass()`)instead of specifying css directly in the JS.  It keeps the styles all where they should be.

jQuery

```
$('#foo').toggleClass('newClass', $('#foo2 img').length > 2);
```

CSS

```
.newClass { margin-top: 10px; ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#foo2 img').length > 2) {
  $('#foo').css('margin-top', 20);
}
```